# Where to change cmake variable values?

Tags: point-cloud-library, pcl

I m having 2 versions of PCL in my UBUNTU 20.04 system, 1.9 and 1.12. In a project I want to use 1.9 version but

`include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})`

above line includes version 1.12 in the project.
Where is the `PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS` value stored and how to update it?

Answer (score 0):

You are giving very few details to go on. However, in your CmakeLists.txt you presumably have a line like

```
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
```

This looks for an installed version of PCL on your system, and if it finds one, then it sets the variables like `PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS`.

Since you have multiple versions installed, it is presumably finding a different version than what you want. If you want a specific version, then you could try

```
find_package(PCL 1.9 EXACT REQUIRED)
```

Comment: So `PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS` cannot be set manually?

Comment: That is a variable that is set by the find_package command. I think the find_package command also sets some other variables like the library directories. In any case, these are all just variables. You can of course override them by using the 'set' command... 'set(PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS home/blah)'. Just make sure to do that after any find_package command, or your variable will be overridden.